# Autoshift with autohotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey, remapping

I wanted to play with autoshift functionality. That is, if any of the alphanumeric keys is pressed longer than some timer, "shift" is automatically applied.

I would imagine that someone has already implemented this or very similar functionality on autohotkey. However, I am complete newbie with autohotkey and I am having troubles for finding relevant examples. Could someone point me to them or give me some tips about how to get started?

Answer (score 1):

```
; create an array/object of the keys you want shift:
Keys := ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

; create a hotkey once for each key in this object, using a For-Loop:
For each, key in Keys
    Hotkey, $%key%, Shift_Key ; the $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used
return

Shift_Key:
    ThisHotkey := StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "$") ; remove the $ prefix 
    KeyWait, %ThisHotkey%, T0.3 ; wait max. 0.3 seconds for the key to be released
    If (ErrorLevel) ; if the command timed out (long press, the key is still pressed after 0.3 seconds)
        SendInput, +%ThisHotkey% ; "shift" it
    else
        SendInput, %ThisHotkey%
    KeyWait, %ThisHotkey% ; don't repeat the action before the key is released
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm

Comment: For anyone following up, on Win 10 this script works for individual characters typed slowly, but for me it fails badly when typing words and sentences at normal speeds (maybe > 60 WPM).

Comment: @user276198 try https://superuser.com/a/1548890/394258

Comment: Many thanks! That script works but the amount of time I have to hold the letter key down to produce a capital letter is too long. Is there any way to adjust it or make it faster?