# KeyWait misbehaving when implementing Autoshift

Tags: autohotkey

I want to have Autoshift with AHK, I used this scritp: https://superuser.com/a/1396278/47625

```
; create an array/object of the keys you want shift:
Keys := ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

; create a hotkey once for each key in this object, using a For-Loop:
For each, key in Keys
    Hotkey, $%key%, Shift_Key ; the $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used
return

Shift_Key:
    ThisHotkey := StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "$") ; remove the $ prefix 
    KeyWait, %ThisHotkey%, T0.3 ; wait max. 0.3 seconds for the key to be released
    If (ErrorLevel) ; if the command timed out (long press, the key is still pressed after 0.3 seconds)
        SendInput, +%ThisHotkey% ; "shift" it
    else
        SendInput, %ThisHotkey%
    KeyWait, %ThisHotkey% ; don't repeat the action before the key is released
return
```

At first this seemed to work well, there is problem however. When you type rather fast it somehow overwrites previous letters with the last letter typed:

I write within 300 miliseconds:
this
Result is:
ssss

Is there any way how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
; create an array/object of the keys you want shift:
Keys := ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

; create a hotkey once for each key in this object, using a For-Loop:
For each, key in Keys
{   
    Hotkey, $%key%, Shift_Key ; the $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used
    Hotkey, ~$%key% Up, Up_Key
}
return

Shift_Key:
    ThisHotkey := StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "$") ; remove the $ prefix 
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "$" ThisHotKey)
    {
        Text := ThisHotkey
        StringUpper, Text, Text
        ToolTip %Text%
        KeyWait, %ThisHotkey%           
        SendInput, {BS}+%ThisHotkey% ; "shift" it
        ToolTip
    }
    else
        SendInput, %ThisHotkey%
return

Up_Key:
return
```

Comment: Pretty good improvement, however you are unable to write two consecutive capital letters like AAA

Comment: Try the edited answer.

Comment: Works great thank you. I guess it is not possible in AHK to make it work without backspace and initial unshifted symbol appearing, right?